# Create USQL Assembly from DLL in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, dll, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to create a Data Lake Analytics database assembly from a DLL located in **Azure Blob Storage**.

According to the USQL language reference guide this is possible, although doesn't give any examples as to what needs to go into the FROM reference... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt763293.aspx

Here's my USQL code snippet.

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY IF NOT EXISTS [dbo].[PurpleFrog.DataLakeHelperFunctions] 
FROM "https://RemovedActual.net/datafactorysupportingfiles/PurpleFrog.DataLakeHelperFunctions.dll";
```

I can successfully create the assembly if I reference the DLL is in the context of Data Lake Storage. Like this:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY IF NOT EXISTS [dbo].[PurpleFrog.DataLakeHelperFunctions] 
FROM "Assemblies/PurpleFrog.DataLakeHelperFunctions.dll";
```

This works, probably because Visual Studio understands where my Data Lake local root directory is etc. However I don't want the DLL stored here.

So...

I have tried changing the access permissions on my blob storage container to allow public read access. Which gives the following error during a local summit:

> E_CSC_USER_CANNOTREADASSEMBLY: Cannot create assembly
>   'dbo.[PurpleFrog.DataLakeHelperFunctions]' because file
>   'https://RemovedActual.net/datafactorysupportingfiles/PurpleFrog.DataLakeHelperFunctions.dll'
>   could not be read.

I have also tried creating an Shared Access Signature URI for the file. Which gives this error during a local summit:

> E_CSC_USER_INVALIDFILENAME: Invalid file name:
>   'https://RemovedActual.net/datafactorysupportingfiles/PurpleFrog.DataLakeHelperFunctions.dll?st=2016-11-28T09%3A52%3A00Z&se=2016-11-29T09%3A52%3A00Z&sp=r&sv=2015-12-11&sr=c&sig=RemovedActual'.
>   Illegal characters in path.

I'm not sure what else I can do here to reference the DLL. Is the language guide wrong? Is this actually possible? What am I missing?

Many thanks for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U-SQL currently only understands the `wasb` and `adl` URI schemes and not `http(s)`.

Can you use the `wasb` scheme that points to your blob storage container and dll?

E.g.,

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY IF NOT EXISTS [dbo].[PurpleFrog.DataLakeHelperFunctions] 
FROM "wasb://container@account/helperfunctions/DataLakeHelperFunctions.dll";
```

Note that you will have to register the blob store account with your ADL account (you can do so through the portal).

Comment: Thanks Mike. This works, but only if I summit from Visual Studio to Azure. Creating the assembly locally doesn't work with the wasb URI. Something for the next version of the VS tools maybe :-)

Comment: Correct, local run does not provide access to cloud resources. http://aka.ms/adlfeedback would be a great place to request the capability.

Comment: Done. Thanks Mike. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/17282363-visual-studio-support-for-assembly-creation-from

Comment: how are we supposed to know the URL of a file? i keep gettin this errror that it cannot find the file